# Running code from python has different permissions then from cmd

Tags: python, windows, cmd, privileges

I'm writing a python script which lists all the files in "c:/windows/system32/" , but unfortunately I see fewer files than the original files list .

**The first Script**

```
import os
os.system("cmd.exe \k dir c:\windows\system32")
```

I took a look at the privileges and I noticed that they both have the same privileges .

**The second Script**

```
import os
os.system("start cmd.exe \k whoami /PRIV")
```

I took a screenshot that shows exactly the issue .

The left window is cmd.exe from the python script and the right window is cmd.exe who launched directly from windows explorer.

[image: The screenshot]

Can someone help me understand why python shows fewer files than cmd.exe ?

Thank you for any help !

Comment: the screenshot doesn't help. What would help would be a textual diff of the 2 dir contents. Try redirecting outputs to files and [edit] your question with the contents.

Comment: Python does not collect that information, Windows does.

Comment: You're probably running 32-bit Python, for which `os.system` runs 32-bit cmd.exe, so `%SystemRoot%\System32` is redirected to `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64`.

Comment: @eryksun thank you !!